Nextjs build failed because of aws-sdk webpack errors
I am trying to build my nextjs project but facing below error.
./node_modules/.pnpm/@aws-sdk+middleware-sdk-s3@3.624.0/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-es/s3-express/functions/s3ExpressHttpSigningMiddleware.js + 33 modules
Cannot get final name for export 'DEFAULT_MAX_ATTEMPTS' of ./node_modules/.pnpm/@smithy+util-retry@3.0.3/node_modules/@smithy/util-retry/dist-es/index.js


> Build failed because of webpack errors
 ELIFECYCLE  Command failed with exit code 1.

Below is my package.json file where I am import alot of packages. I have tried reseting cache, deleting node_modules folder, deleting pnpm-lock.yaml file and then reinstalling packages but its not working.
Found a solution of on github by adding below line to next.config.js
 experimental: { serverComponentsExternalPackages: [ 'aws-sdk' ] }

but above is also not working.
Below is package.json file.
{
  "name": "drippy_nextjs",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "postinstall": "prisma generate",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@auth/prisma-adapter": "^1.0.11",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.624.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-presigned-post": "^3.624.0",
    "@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.624.0",
    "@googleapis/content": "^20.0.1",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.18",
    "@heroicons/react": "^2.1.1",
    "@hookform/resolvers": "^3.3.4",
    "@next/bundle-analyzer": "^14.1.3",
    "@next/third-parties": "^14.1.3",
    "@prisma/client": "^5.8.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-accordion": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-aspect-ratio": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-avatar": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-checkbox": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-dialog": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-label": "^2.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-progress": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-radio-group": "^1.1.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-scroll-area": "^1.0.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-select": "^2.0.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-separator": "^1.0.3",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-tabs": "^1.0.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-toast": "^1.1.5",
    "@radix-ui/react-tooltip": "^1.0.7",
    "@smithy/util-retry": "^3.0.3",
    "@t3-oss/env-nextjs": "^0.9.2",
    "@tailwindcss/typography": "^0.5.10",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.17.10",
    "@tanstack/react-table": "^8.11.7",
    "@trpc/client": "11.0.0-next-beta.193",
    "@trpc/next": "11.0.0-next-beta.193",
    "@trpc/react-query": "11.0.0-next-beta.193",
    "@trpc/server": "11.0.0-next-beta.193",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.2.2",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.21",
    "@types/heap": "^0.2.34",
    "@upstash/ratelimit": "^1.0.1",
    "@upstash/redis": "^1.28.3",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1669.0",
    "axios": "^1.6.5",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "cmdk": "^0.2.0",
    "crypto-js": "^4.2.0",
    "date-fns": "^3.2.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "embla-carousel-react": "8.0.0-rc19",
    "google-merchant-feed": "^0.1.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.8",
    "heap": "^0.2.7",
    "hex-color-to-color-name": "^1.0.2",
    "is-ua-webview": "^1.1.2",
    "keyword-extractor": "^0.0.28",
    "lucide-react": "^0.309.0",
    "next": "14.1.3",
    "next-auth": "^4.24.5",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.8",
    "razorpay": "^2.9.2",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.1",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.49.3",
    "react-icons": "^5.0.1",
    "react-intersection-observer": "^9.5.3",
    "react-parallax-tilt": "^1.7.212",
    "react-responsive-masonry": "^2.1.7",
    "react-sortable": "^2.0.0",
    "react-sortablejs": "^6.1.4",
    "react-swipeable": "^7.0.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.4",
    "recharts": "^2.10.4",
    "schema-dts": "^1.1.2",
    "scrypt-async": "^2.0.1",
    "shortid": "^2.2.16",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "superjson": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.0",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "vaul": "^0.8.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zod": "^3.22.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^6.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^14.2.1",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/node": "^20",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.14",
    "@types/react": "^18",
    "@types/react-beautiful-dnd": "^13.1.8",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/react-responsive-masonry": "^2.1.3",
    "@types/react-slick": "^0.23.13",
    "@types/shortid": "^0.0.32",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "14.0.4",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "^29.7.0",
    "jest-mock-extended": "^3.0.5",
    "postcss": "^8",
    "prisma": "^5.8.0",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.3.0",
    "typescript": "^5"
  },
  "prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
  }
}



I had the same problem. I solved it by:
Adding the experimental addition to next.config.js
experimental: {serverComponentsExternalPackages: ['@aws-sdk']},
Keep my two aws packages in these versions, it works also with higher packages as far as I tested.
"@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.540.0",
"@aws-sdk/s3-request-presigner": "^3.540.0",

And I moved the nextjs version to 14.1.0.
This eventually worked. Despite it being quite a specific solution, it might help if you don't want to upgrade nextjs yet.
Can you try it with next 14.1.0, because with me 14.1.3 didn't work.
